# SDL and C++ Class...how to separate this code?

Tags: c++, class, sdl

I am learning SDL Programming from lazyfoo.net.
I am using Xcode...I m trying to split this single code to three different files like class.cpp, class.hpp and main.cpp, but I can't able to do because there are some global variables declared...Need your advise.

Tutorial link..
http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/10_color_keying/index.php

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't complete. Please take a look at Biffen's comment, and post a more concrete problem.

That said, the refactor you're looking to perform is quite simple. I'm not going to install my own copy of SDL to confirm, but here's the approach you should be taking.

Instead of a generic file name like class.cpp/h use something more descriptive! The class going into these files is LTexture, so name your files to match.

> **LTexture.h**
>
> - The `LTexture` class definition
> - `SDL_Renderer* gRenderer`
>
> **LTexture.cpp**
>
> - Include *LTexture.h*
> - Every function in the `LTexture` class (i.e. signatures that begin with LTexture::)
>
> **Main.cpp**
>
> - Include *LTexture.h*
> - Everything else